# autotools: Is there an built-in option to run binaries in parallel within a single test (testing file locks)?

Tags: autotools

I search for a portable way to run a two binaries in parallel for testing file/record locking. Something like

```
AT_CHECK[$COMPILE binary1-locking-something]
AT_CHECK[$COMPILE binary2-checking-the-lock]
AT_CHECK-PARALLEL[$RUN binary1-locking-something, $RUN binary2-checking-the-lock]
```

The only workaround I've thought about so far is to compile a local test driver which calls the first binary asynchronous, then the second one, but it looks like a dirty hack

```
AT_CHECK([$COMPILE binary1-locking-something])
AT_CHECK([$COMPILE binary2-checking-the-lock])
AT_DATA(test-driver,
[[$RUN binary1-locking-something &
$RUN binary2-checking-the-lock
]])
AT_CHECK([./test-driver])
```

Is there any built-in option to do something like this? If not: How to achieve this (I'm not sure the workaround approach will work - and if it does - work on all systems).

Comment: I don't think autotools can do that. Are there any reasons not to use one forking test program that will check the lock between parent and child?

Comment: Thank you for your question for clarification. Yes, the tested system doesn't support a direct fork (at least not yet) and even if It does I'd like to have the testing scenario setup in the testsuite as the "fork feature" in the tested system may be broken, too (it is a multi-OS multi compiler project).